# How to filter in a table to a number not a string?

Tags: html, angular, datagrid, angular4-forms, angular-forms

I would like to search in my table but can only search by Strings.

I use a filter pipe:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

     transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
        if (!items) {
          return [];
        }
        if (!field || !value) {
          return items;
        }

          return items.filter(singleItem => singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
      }
```

The project is a field with numbers

```
<tr *ngFor="let todo of todos | filter: 'project' : searchString; let i = index">//It doesnt works.
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED

```
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value) {
      return items;
    }

    return items.filter(singleItem => value.toLowerCase());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `toLowerCase()` on a `string`, not on a `number`.

A solution would be casting it to a string first, like so:

```js
(singleItem[field] + '').toLowerCase()
```

#### Update

There is a boolean predicate missing in your updated version of filter, which is needed to decide whether an item should be filtered out or not, but `value.toLowerCase()` does always evaluate to `true` for non-empty strings for `value`, hence nothing gets filtered out:

```js
items.filter(singleItem => value.toLowerCase());
```

Instead, you should do something like:

```js
isIncluded(item: any, value: any, field: any): boolean {
  // transform item to a string, in case it's of type number
  const itemString = (item[field] + '').toLowerCase();
  // transform value to a string ...
  const valueString = (value + '').toLowerCase();
  // decide, whether item should be filtered out
  return itemString.includes(valueString);
}


transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
   // (...)

   return items.filter(item => this.isIncluded(item, value, field));
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, i tried that but it doesnt works. May i should do more changes?
Thanks

Comment: You also call `value.toLowerCase()`, you might have to do the same there. Also, what do you mean by it doesn't work? Is there an exception on the console?

Comment: Still having problems?

Comment: it doesnt works. i updated my post woul you mind look if the code is the same you said?